# i want to use pdf function in php multicell in one line parallel cell text left top align

Tags: php, fpdf

into cell tag how can i use text in left top if the text block is large.
there is the main problem in Multicell i can't use twomulticell parallel .

```
  $pdf->MultiCell(60, 6, "".$row['particular'], 1, 'L', FALSE);
    $pdf->Cell(40,50,"".$row['quantity'],1,0,"l");
```

Answer (score 5):

The MultiCell method has no $ln parameter like the Cell method (Just a side note: Internally a MultiCell creates the lines by several Cell calls). If you need to stay at the same line with a multicell you have to do this with your own logic. E.g.:

```
$y = $pdf->GetY();
$x = $pdf->GetX();
$width = 60;
$pdf->MultiCell($width, 6, 'particular', 1, 'L', FALSE);
$pdf->SetXY($x + $width, $y);
$pdf->Cell(40,50, 'quantity', 1, 0, "l");
```

Comment: BTW follow a spec that helped me a lot -> http://www.fpdf.org/download/multicell.pdf